# On-board USB ports are not working but front case ports are

Tags: usb

I recently built a server box that is running 15.10.  The system has four USB ports.  Two ports are on the back (on-board) and two ports are on the front of the case (connect to MB header).  The two front ports work fine.  However, the two back ports do not work.  They will provide power to a connected device.  But, the device will not enumerate.  I am lost as to where to start.

MSI A68HI AC, AMD A8 7600, G.SKILL 8GB, PC3 17000, SanDisk 120GB SSD, 2x WD Blue 1TB

lsusb:
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp.
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: Post the output of `lsusb`.

Comment: Hi Raphael,  I've posted the output of lsusb.

Comment: You've got 9 usb ports on your system. Some are USB-1 some 2 and some 3... Are you sure you're not running into power issues/HW compatibility problems? Have you tested something simple like a mouse on all ports to identify them correctly?

Comment: Hi Fabby,  I only have 4 USB ports on my system.  Two are on the MB and two are on the front of the case.